# XSLT to uncomment AND remove xml version tag

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I need help using XSLT to uncomment the XML and remove xml version tag:

Original XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<TSC>
<customApiError>
<!--<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<error>
    <httpStatusCode>400</httpStatusCode>
    <httpMessage>Bad Request</httpMessage>
</error>-->
</customApiError>
</TSC>
```

Converted XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<TSC>
<customApiError>
<error>
    <httpStatusCode>400</httpStatusCode>
    <httpMessage>Bad Request</httpMessage>
</error>
</customApiError>
</TSC>
```

Comment: Which XSLT 1.0 processor do you use? A clean solution is only possible if you can use/implement a processor specific extension function to parse the comment's content as XML and then output it using `xsl:copy-of`.

Answer (score 2):

If your processor supports [`disable-output-escaping`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#disable-output-escaping) then you can do

```
<xsl:template match="comment()">
  <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., '?>')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
</xsl:template>
```

All the usual caveats about `disable-output-escaping` apply.